# Handle Trailing Slash in angular 4 using ng-2 ui-router-2

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-ui-router

I'm beginner to Angular 4, I have issue with trailing slash in ng-2 ui-router-2.

when i hit this url, its works fine

> http://localhost:8000/dashboard/home

but by adding / at end, it does not display page

> http://localhost:8000/dashboard/home/

I searched it, but found solution for ui-router 1, one of solution was to use

> $urlMatcherFactoryProvider.strictMode(false);

and some one said to add rule like this

```
  $urlRouterProvider.rule(function($injector, $location) {

var path = $location.path();
var hasTrailingSlash = path[path.length-1] === '/';

if(hasTrailingSlash) {

  //if last charcter is a slash, return the same url without the slash  
  var newPath = path.substr(0, path.length - 1); 
  return newPath; 
}});
```

How i will do this in Angular 4 using ng2 ui-router-2??

Answer (score 1):

That is configured using the `UrlService`.  Add some code to your router config function which sets the strictMode.

https://ui-router.github.io/ng2/docs/latest/interfaces/url.urlconfigapi.html#strictmode

```
export function routerConfig(router: UIRouter) {
  router.urlService.config.strictMode(false);
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [        
    UIRouterModule.forRoot({ config: routerConfig })
  ]
}) export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Chris can you please tell me where to place this code?? In State.ts file or module ts. As i'm beginner , so i could not get it where to place it